# How can I return grep results one line at a time in order to use the parsed data in another script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, terminal

I have a script that I use at work that I'd like to expand on a bit.  The script I'm currently using takes an IP address as an arg and pushes a zip file to a specific directory on that device.  The device is an Android device, and the specific directory I push to is used to trigger a device recovery using the new data that was pushed.

I'm looking to try to find a way to scan the network, identify all android devices attached, then push the new firmwares to each of them.  Since the push part is already easily accomplished, what I need it to find a way to scan and identify the IP's for each attached devices.

I've come up with:

```
nmap -sL 10.111.1.0/24 | grep android | grep -oE '([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}'
```

which will bounce through the network, find anything with "android" in the line, then parse out and return the IP address of those lines.  The problem is, I don't know how to take the IP addresses one at a time and feed them to a script from here.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop and a subshell anytime you have this pattern where you want to act on the result of a pipeline:

```
for ip in $( nmap -sL 10.111.1.0/24 | grep android | grep -oE '([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}' ); do
  echo "W00t! I found this ${ip}"
  /path/to/script "${ip}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a while loop and parse whatever you get from the grep with a set.

```
(nmap -sL 10.111.1.0/24 | grep android | grep -oE '([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}' | \
while read -a device; do
    echo ${device[0]}
    echo ${device[1]}
    ...
    /path/to/script ${device[2]} #the number that represents the ip address (I don t know wich one it will be depends what your grep gives)
 done)
```

Now you can get the IP address and push it in the script

Answer (score 1):

Read it into an array:

```
read -a devices < <(nmap -sL 10.111.1.0/24 | grep android | grep -oE '([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}')
```

Then send it to the script:

```
/path/to/script "${devices[@]}"
```